# Copy a range from excel to another workbook in a new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA macros and have taught myself some code but I'm struggling with my current piece of work and can't find the answer I am looking for.

I want to copy a range of cells (B3:N21) from one workbook to another "master" workbook - which seems simple enough - but I would like it to copy into a blank/new worksheet in the Master copy every time the Macro is run.

The range contains formulas, I would only need the values copied to the Master workbook.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C5").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").activate
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D1:D5").PasteSpecial _ 
 Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd 
End With
```

I think you only need paste special, this is an example

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add Before:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)      This can be the code to add a new worksheet

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

    Dim masterWb As Workbook
    Dim mySht As Worksheet

    Set mySht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet '<~~ assuming you're copying values from active worksheet of the workbook the macro resides in
                                         '    beware: if you start the macro while the active sheet is not the one you want, this will lead to unespected results

    Set masterWb = Workbooks("Master") '<~~ Change "Master" with whatever name your master workbook must have
                                       '    beware: we're assuming "Master" workbook is already open, otherwise this line will throw an error

    With masterWb.Worksheets.Add
        .Range("B3:N21").Value = mySht.Range("B3:N21").Value
    End With

End Sub
```

mind the comments

the code above can be reduce to a much less verbose (and self explanatory, too) one like follows

```
Sub main2()    
    Workbooks("Master").Worksheets.Add.Range("B3:N21").Value = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B3:N21").Value    
End Sub
```

where apply the same comments of the lengthy code, which is:

- assuming you're copying values from active worksheet of the workbook the macro resides in

  beware: if you start the macro while the active sheet is not the one you want, this will lead to unespected results
- change "Master" with whatever name your master workbook must have

  beware: we're assuming "Master" workbook is already open, otherwise an error would be thrown

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, however, when I run the macro I get a runtime error saying "Subscript out of range". I've changed the filename to "Master" as per your comments. Any further help would be great thank you

Comment: you should be so kind to say which line throws that error. should it be `Set masterWb = Workbooks("Master")` line, you must first ensure to have coped with all my comments assumptions and warnings

Comment: My apologies, it is the Set masterWb = Workbooks("Master") line which throws this error. I have taken account of your comments and ensured that the Master version is open, and I am in the active sheet I would like to copy my range from

Comment: is the _Master version_ a workbook named exactly "Master"? Does _the active sheet I would like to copy my range from_ belong to the workbook where the macro resides in?

Comment: Yes it is named exactly "Master" and the macro is assigned to a Test button in the workbook my range is to be copied from

Comment: so there's a _Test button_... the "Master" workbook issue is not related to this, so that if you actually have an open `Workbook` named "Master" and the macro gives an error hitting the `Set masterWb = Workbooks("Master")` line, then I couldn't say why. While on the side of _active sheet vs button issue_: is the button residing in the same `Worksheet` where data are to be copied from? does the macro assigned to the button reside in the same `Workbook` the button `Worksheet` belongs to?

Comment: @B.Lewis: did you get through it?